# Using Generics in Linq Query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to write a generic function that generates an Xelement based on a list of objects, and a property of the object

Currently I have this code copied and pasted in several spots

```
 InputElementsArray = New XElement(New XElement("ArrayInputs", _
                   New XElement("InputName", "TestFailedRefDesList"), _
                   New XElement("DataType", "StringArray"), _
                   New XElement("ValueList", From d In _PassFailItem.FailureDetails Select New XElement("InputValue", d.RefDes))))
    InputElements.Add(InputElementsArray)
```

The above code works fine for me, but I would much rather create one single function that does the same task given an object and a property

```
Private Shared Function CreateBaseArrayInputs(Of T)(ByVal ListOfItems As List(Of T)) As XElement
    Dim InputElementsArray As XElement = _
         New XElement("ArrayInputs", _
                  New XElement("InputName", "TestFailureCodeList"), _
                  New XElement("DataType", "StringArray"), _
                  New XElement("ValueList", From d In ListOfItems Select New XElement("InputValue", d)))
    Return InputElementsArray
End Function
```

I am unsure about how I can generically set the property of d to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using XML literals, I would pass your value selector into your function like this:

```
Private Shared Function CreateBaseArrayInputs(Of T, TValue)( _
        ByVal ListOfItems As List(Of T), _
        ByVal selector As Func(Of T, TValue)) As XElement

    Return <ArrayInputs>
               <InputName>TestFailureCodeList</InputName>
               <DataType>StringArray</DataType>
               <ValueList>
                   <%= From d In ListOfItems _
                       Select <InputValue><%= selector(d) %></InputValue> %>
               </ValueList>
           </ArrayInputs>
End Function
```

Which you would call like this:

```
 Dim TestArray As XElement = CreateBaseArrayInputs(_PassFailItem.FailureDetails, Function(d) d.FailureCodes)
```

Comment: Thats very similar to the code that I would up using, it just simplfies the process of passing in the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can specify a property using generics. I C# you cat put a restriction on T using the [where keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx), but it seems that this is not avaible in VB.NET.

The restriction would allow you to specify that you T-elements have to implement an interface, and therefore you would know that the properties for that interface would be availble.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot that VB and C# do not share keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. It is not as elegant as I would have liked, but it still works

Here is the calling code

```
 Dim TestArray As XElement = CreateBaseArrayInputs((From d In _PassFailItem.FailureDetails Select New XElement("InputValue", d.FailureCodes)))
```

Here is the Called Function

```
Private Shared Function CreateBaseArrayInputs(ByVal ListOfItems As IEnumerable(Of XElement)) As XElement
    Dim InputElementsArray As XElement = _
         New XElement("ArrayInputs", _
                  New XElement("InputName", "TestFailureCodeList"), _
                  New XElement("DataType", "StringArray"), _
                  New XElement("ValueList", ListOfItems))
    Return InputElementsArray
End Function
```